# Registration error with BlueMix

Tags: authentication, registration, ibm-cloud

I am getting `Registration Failed` while signing into [IBM Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net) even though I have an IBM valid account created.
I have given my phone number and valid email address. I logged in through having valid IBM ID in Bluemix.

Answer (score 3):

The [status page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net) is showing there are issues.

Nov 16, 2015 10:25 AM
Login issues in Bluemix public regions
Users are experiencing issues logging into Bluemix in the US-South, EU-GB and AU...

Answer (score 1):

On today there have been login issues in Bluemix public regions.
As reported on Bluemix Status Page

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

> Users are experiencing issues logging into Bluemix in the US-South, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions. The team is aware and investigating a resolution.

Update 2015-11-16 17:45 UTC: The issues with logging into the public Bluemix regions is now resolved and operating as expected

I suggest to try again in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

As I see, there is a maintenance working. Maybe, this is the source of registiration problem.

[UPDATE: Dec 12 10:01 am EST] Bluemix platform maintenance -- all regions - December 12 - December 17